# How can I enter a password using Perl and replace the characters with '*'?

Tags: perl, terminal, passwords, echo

I have a Perl script that requires the user to enter a password. How can I echo only '*' in place of the character that the user types, as they type it?

I'm using Windows XP/Vista.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can play with Term::ReadKey. Here is a very simple example, with some detection for backspace and delete key. I've tested it on Mac OS X 10.5 but according to the [ReadKey manual](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TermReadKey/ReadKey.pm) it should work under Windows. The [manual](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TermReadKey/ReadKey.pm) indicates that under Windows using non-blocking reads (`ReadKey(-1)`) will fail. That's why I'm using ReadKey(0) who's basically `getc` (more on getc in the [libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Character-Input.html)).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                                                                

use strict;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
use warnings;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
use Term::ReadKey;                                                                                                                                                                                             

my $key = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                   
my $password = "";                                                                                                                                                                                             

print "\nPlease input your password: ";                                                                                                                                                                        

# Start reading the keys                                                                                                                                                                                       
ReadMode(4); #Disable the control keys                                                                                                                                                                         
while(ord($key = ReadKey(0)) != 10)                                                                                                                                                                            
# This will continue until the Enter key is pressed (decimal value of 10)                                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    # For all value of ord($key) see http://www.asciitable.com/                                                                                                                                                
    if(ord($key) == 127 || ord($key) == 8) {                                                                                                                                                                   
        # DEL/Backspace was pressed                                                                                                                                                                            
        #1. Remove the last char from the password                                                                                                                                                             
        chop($password);                                                                                                                                                                                       
        #2 move the cursor back by one, print a blank character, move the cursor back by one                                                                                                                   
        print "\b \b";                                                                                                                                                                                         
    } elsif(ord($key) < 32) {                                                                                                                                                                                  
        # Do nothing with these control characters                                                                                                                                                             
    } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        $password = $password.$key;                                                                                                                                                                            
        print "*(".ord($key).")";                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ReadMode(0); #Reset the terminal once we are done                                                                                                                                                              
print "\n\nYour super secret password is: $password\n";
```

Comment: This does not work under Windows. It works fine until you come to hit the enter key, when you have to press it four time for it to react. If you use ReadMode(2), then it works fine, but doesn't echo until you hit return. Not displaying the * may be an acceptable alternative

Comment: It does not work on Windows because the decimal ascii value of the Enter or Return key is 13 (CR: carriage return). Once you replace the line while(ord($key = ReadKey(0)) != 10) with while(ord($key = ReadKey(0)) != 13), it works better :)

Comment: You will probably also want to check for "\x03" (^C); also, you will probably want to emit "\b \b" only if length($password) > 0 or based on chop()'s return value (to avoid erasing the prompt if the user keeps on backtracking)

Comment: 1. Damien is right: works like a charm under Windows when added 13 for the key test.
2. Vladr: no need to test for ^C under Windows, neither for ^Break. ReadKey seems immune to these interrupts. Implemented your ideas about "\b..." w/ length(pwd). Perfect.
3. All other modules IOPrompt[er] and similar are a no go under Windows (7/64 and 10/64). This solution is the one.

Answer (score 24):

In the past I have used [IO::Prompt](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-Prompt/) for this.

```
use IO::Prompt;
my $password = prompt('Password:', -e => '*');
print "$password\n";
```

Comment: *[STATUS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-Prompt/lib/IO/Prompt.pm#STATUS): This module is no longer being maintained. Use the IO::Prompter module instead.*

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want use any packages... Only for UNIX

```
system('stty','-echo');
chop($password=<STDIN>);
system('stty','echo');
```

Comment: `chomp` would be better than `chop`

Answer (score 8):

You should take a look at either [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ReadKey) or [Win32::Console](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Console). You can use those modules to read the single key strokes and emit '*' or whathever.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Pierr-Luc's program, just added some control on the backslashes. With this, you can't keep pressing backslash forever:

```
sub passwordDisplay() {
    my $password = "";
    # Start reading the keys
    ReadMode(4); #Disable the control keys
    my $count = 0;
    while(ord($key = ReadKey(0)) != 10) {
            # This will continue until the Enter key is pressed (decimal value of 10)
            # For all value of ord($key) see http://www.asciitable.com/
            if(ord($key) == 127 || ord($key) == 8) {
                    # DEL/Backspace was pressed
                    if ($count > 0) {
                            $count--;
                            #1. Remove the last char from the password
                            chop($password);
                            #2 move the cursor back by one, print a blank character, move the cursor back by one
                            print "\b \b";
                    }
            }
            elsif(ord($key) >= 32) {
                    $count++;
                    $password = $password.$key;
                    print "*";
            }
    }
    ReadMode(0); #Reset the terminal once we are done
    return $password;
}
```

Comment: No need for $count, length($password) will do.

Answer (score 0):

using Pierr-Luc's program

```
# Start reading the keys                                                                                                                                                                                       
ReadMode(4); #Disable the control keys                                                                                                                                                                         
while(ord($key = ReadKey(0)) != '13' )                                                                                                                                                                            
# This will continue until the Enter key is pressed (decimal value of 10)                                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    # For all value of ord($key) see http://www.asciitable.com/                                                                                                                                                
    if(ord($key) == 127 || ord($key) == 8 && (length($password) > 0)) {                                                                                                                                                                   
        # DEL/Backspace was pressed                                                                                                                                                                            
        #1. Remove the last char from the password                                                                                                                                                             
        chop($password);                                                                                                                                                                                       
        #2 move the cursor back by one, print a blank character, move the cursor back by one                                                                                                                   
        print "\b \b";                                                                                                                                                                                         
    } elsif(ord($key) > 32) {                                                                                                                                                                                  
        $password = $password.$key;                                                                                                                                                                            
        print "*";                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ReadMode(0); #Reset the terminal once we are done
```

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried storing the string (so that your program can still read it) and find out its length then create a string of the same length, but only use '*'?

Comment: Replacing the character with * as they type it.