# how to get the string in hidden way

Tags: perl, unix

I am new to perl

I want to get password in invisible way

example:
Enter the Password..?

**

it may space or any other symbol

while giving the input of the specified string

It should not visible to other even a input entering person

Is there any way to getting input in hidden way in perl

Comment: So, you want to turn off echoing?  You'll need to use one of the terminal management packages.  You can find them on http://search.cpan.org/ without much difficulty.  You can also check out the [core modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/index.html) such as [`Term::Readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ReadLine.html) and [`Term::UI`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/UI.html).

Comment: Do you want it inside a Shell or is it a CGI-Script or what exactly? Maybe [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239465/hiding-user-input) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701078/how-can-i-enter-a-password-using-perl-and-replace-the-characters-with) is what you need.

Comment: Please make sure to search before posting. The duplicate question linked above was the second result for a Google search for ["perl read password from terminal"](http://www.google.com/search?q=perl+read+password+from+terminal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Recipe 15.10: "Reading Passwords"](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch15_11.htm)

> Use the CPAN module `Term::ReadKey`, set the input mode to `noecho` , and then use `ReadLine` :
>
> ```
> use Term::ReadKey;
>
> ReadMode('noecho');
> $password = ReadLine(0);
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Using System Function with stty command.

```
print "Enter The Password : ";  
system ("stty -echo");  
my $password = <STDIN>;  
system ("stty echo");

chomp $password;
```