# IO::Prompter - Is it possible to disable history?

Tags: perl, input, history

Is it possible - when prompting for a password - to configure `prompt` from [IO::Prompter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3A%3APrompter) in a way that the input is not added to the history?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.1;
use utf8;
use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );
use IO::Prompter;


my $password = prompt( 'Password: ', -echo => '' );
say $password;
$password = prompt( 'Password: ', -echo => '' );
say $password;
$password = prompt( 'Password: ', -echo => '' );
say $password;
$password = prompt( 'Password: ', -echo => '' );
say $password;
$password = prompt( 'Password: ', -echo => '' );
say $password;
```

Comment: Here is a similar question for refernce: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701078/how-can-i-enter-a-password-using-perl-and-replace-the-characters-with

Comment: What does `IO::Prompter` add to the history if echoing is disabled?

Comment: @mugenkenichi, I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not possible when you wrote the question, but IO::Prompter has been patched to include the special history set `NONE` which disables the history.

The first version of IO::Prompter with the patch is 0.004003.

http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/IO-Prompter-0.004003/lib/IO/Prompter.pm

```
my $password = prompt('Password: ', -hNONE, -echo => '');

my $force_the_user_to_type = prompt('Type something: ', -hNONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using other modules, I suggest [Term::ReadKey](https://metacpan.org/module/Term%3a%3aReadKey)

Here is a sample script I wrote that will disable echo for reading, read a line and return what it received for testing purposes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ReadKey;

ReadMode 2;
my $pw;
print "Enter password ";
while ( not defined( $pw ) ) {
  $pw = ReadLine(-1); 
}
chomp $pw;
print "\nI got $pw entered\n";
ReadMode 0;
```

Comment: What is the advantage of the solution with a while over simply writing my $pw = ReadLine(0); chomp $pw?

Comment: @sid_com I guess I wanted to make it clear that it would wait for input.  There is no difference.