# How can Perl prompt for a password without showing it in the terminal?

Tags: perl, terminal, passwords

How can I prompt a terminal user for a password without showing the password in the terminal? There's a similar question for [How can I enter a password using Perl and replace the characters with '*'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701078/2766176), but the answers appear to be out-of-date or broken.

I was looking for answers to this question and wasn't satisfied with the questions on later pages of results that had the answer tangentially to other concerns.

Also, [perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-ask-the-user-for-a-password%3f) has an example that is incomplete (oh, and who used to maintain that ;).

```
 use Term::ReadKey;
 ReadMode('noecho');
 my $password = ReadLine(0);
```

When you do that without resetting the terminal, nothing else echos! Oops!

I'm also looking for newer answers or modules we can provide to people who want to do this.

Comment: did something change here the last years? - for me (as of 09/2020) this works with LWP::UserAgent: `print "password please: ";
ReadMode('noecho');
my $pass=ReadLine(0);
chomp($pass);
$request->authorization_basic('username', $pass);`

Comment: LWP doesn't have anything to do with it. Otherwise you have the same code.

Comment: Correct. What I meant is, that I used those lines from perlfaq8 in the context of LWP (that is maybe useless information) - and in that context it worked perfectly fine. No problems, no need to reset the terminal. (maybe the problems you saw 4 years ago where fixed? dont know)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use [Term::ReadKey](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Term::ReadKey), this works:

```
sub prompt_for_password {
    require Term::ReadKey;

    # Tell the terminal not to show the typed chars
    Term::ReadKey::ReadMode('noecho');

    print "Type in your secret password: ";
    my $password = Term::ReadKey::ReadLine(0);

    # Rest the terminal to what it was previously doing
    Term::ReadKey::ReadMode('restore');

    # The one you typed didn't echo!
    print "\n";

    # get rid of that pesky line ending (and works on Windows)
    $password =~ s/\R\z//;

    # say "Password was <$password>"; # check what you are doing :)

    return $password;
}
```

Comment: This can be improved by deciding to trim leading or trailing whitespace, and how to remove something from the end. On Windows `chomp` might not do the right thing.

Comment: With the routine above, `chomp` does do the right thing on Windows. For the problem with `IO::Prompter` see [RT #118255](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=118255).

Comment: This solution doesn't restore to terminal to the previous (*echo*) state if the user presses Ctrl-*C* at the password prompt. To solve this, a `$SIG{INT} = sub { ... };` handler has to be set up.

Comment: It's a community wiki, so you can edit the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [IO::Prompter](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Prompter):

```
$ perl -MIO::Prompter -wE '$pass = prompt("Password: ", -echo => "*"); $pass =~ s/\R\z//; say $pass'
```

It is probably overkill for just asking for the password, but it is useful if you need to elicit other types of user input as well. Note that you do need [Term::ReadKey](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadKey) for the password masking function to work. Unfortunately, the module does not warn you about this at build time. You will know you are in this situation if the one-liner above generates the warning:

> #### [Warning: next input will be in plaintext](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Prompter#Warning:-next-input-will-be-in-plaintext)
>
> The `prompt()` subroutine was called with the -echo flag, but the `Term::ReadKey` module was not available to implement this feature. The input will proceed as normal, but this warning is issued to ensure that the user doesn't type in something secret, expecting it to remain hidden, which it won't.

How that warning message corresponds to the meaning given in the explanation is beyond me, but, oh well.

Note that on Windows the module leaves a `CR` at the end of the input string which `chomp` does not remove (because it is looking for a `CRLF` sequence). That's why I use `\R` in the example above. See [RT #118255](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=118255).

Answer (score 0):

[Term::ReadPassword::Win32](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadPassword::Win32) works on both Win32 and Unix (even though its name suggest otherwise). On Unix it uses [Term::ReadPassword](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadPassword).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ReadPassword::Win32 qw(read_password);
my $input = read_password("Password: ");
say $input;
```

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a short solution which works with standard Perl modules (i.e. without installation). If you can't install from CPAN, you may want to copy-paste code from the modules above.

Answer (score 0):

There are many suggestions online containing `system("stty -echo")`, but that doesn't work on Win32 (it's Unix-only), and the actual robust solution using that quickly becomes complicated (longer than 30 lines, with portability issues): 1. handling Ctrl-*C* is a mess (needs `$SIG{INT} = ...` or more `stty` flags), and 2. it's tricky to get the TTY device filehandle and pass it to `stty` (using shell redirection or some Perl `open(...)` magic), in case stdin, stdout or stderr is redirected.